# Indexing trouble in Google after HTTPs conversion and traffic decline

Tags: seo, https, traffic, google-cache

Our online platform was `http://example.com/`

We have just added SSL traffic from Dec 1 and from there site is getting low traffic and now 90% traffic is down.

`https://www.example.com/`  is our main version now.

But this caused some major issues in google indexing with all four versions pages in Google cache:

```
https://www.example.com/
https://example.com/
http://www.example.com/
http://.example.com/
```

With non-www have been indexed causing major surge in traffic too.

It is being shown like these:

`https://example.com/................`  with descriptions 
(A description for this result is not available because of this site's `robots.txt`)

Is there a way to remove these non-www posts from Google cache or
convert them with our main version i.e. 
`https://www.example.com/..............`

My site's traffic is getting killed almost daily and I need some solutions.

Comment: We seem to get this question every few days. The answer is, Yes. Of course you are! HTTP versus HTTPS, www versus non-www, these are individual sites to search engines. When you change a site from HTTP to HTTPS, traffic will drop from HTTP and HTTPS will increase. It can take months. You are, in effect, starting over. It can take months to regain your traffic. You will have to add a property for HTTPS and www in Google Search Console if you have not already. If everything is working on your site okay, it will just take time to build your search traffic again. Cheers!!

Comment: You do want to check your sites. Make sure that you have a robots.txt file that works properly. If you use an .htaccess file, make sure that is working too. Check your sites out completely. Search will catch up. Search engines are not real-time. Any chnage like the one you made are usually very disruptive. If you have 301 redirects from HTTP and non-www versions of your site to the preferred HTTPS www site, then it will be just a matter of time. Be patient. It will work out.

Comment: `all four versions pages` == duplicated content? maybe this is the cause for the indexing issue? you should have the one and only single version indexed. all another should be 301-redirected

Comment: We have added 301 redirect for all versions but still there are pages 
with https without www
without https 
without www in google indexing
and one month has already being passed. Still traffic is going downhill now down to 90% loss.